# Unmodified question looks modified

Tags: discussion, editing

This is maybe the fourth time I noticed this scenario since the start of this year, so I am curious to know if you have an explanation:

When I clicked on [Questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions), I saw this:

[image]

But when I clicked to read [that question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/195635/numpy-2d-array-anti-diagonal-averaging), I did not see any modifications done to the post by [Gareth Rees](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/11728/gareth-rees) (at least by the time I am posting this).

How come this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gareth has an answer to that question that was posted at 16:14:13Z and self-deleted at 16:19:39Z.

Comment: Is there a reason self-deleted answers don't show up on the timeline? Does this change once 10k tools are unlocked and deleted answers become visible?

Comment: @Mast For me the timeline does show the deleted answer. Unsure though if that's a mod thing or a 10k thing. Can a non-mod 10k user check?

Comment: I don't think that users under 10k can see deleted posts

Comment: I posted a screenshot of how it appears to a 10k+ non-moderator user [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8871/71574).  To answer @Mast's question, yes it changes.  At least I assume it does, because like Simon, I can't see it the other way.  But it does not match the description that others are posting, so I assume my view is different.

Answer (score 5):

This is what the [timeline](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/195635/timeline) looks like to me (10k+, not a moderator).

[image: Timeline]

The deleted answer shows.

Whether <10k users should be able to see this in the timeline so as to explain why the post is showing as modified is unclear.  I believe that the primary argument against showing deleted answers is that some are deleted for reasons, e.g. spam or rude/abusive.

Of course, if the site shouldn't show this in the timeline, then it probably also shouldn't show it on the front page.  But then if it doesn't even show that on the front page, why are we showing the post on the front page?  And not showing a recently modified post (even if the modification was later reversed) is probably hard due to caching.

I suppose that it could be changed from "modified [time] ago", "[author]" to "reversed modification" or similar.  But if so, that should show on the timeline as well.  Because there is a race condition where the front page won't know yet but the timeline should.  The cached view will not always be consistent with the current view.